# How do I sort the items in the ArrayList and change the places of items in another array depending on order in the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, comparator

There is an ArrayList of vehicle objects,used a number of times. Each object has an id and the number of times it was used.

```
ArrayList<Object> usedVehicles = new ArrayList();
```

And there is another array, which keeps all the ids of vehicles.

```
int[] vehicleIDs = database.getVehicleIds();
```

I need to sort elements in **vehicleIDs** array depending on the number of times they were used, obviously the vehicles which have never been used must come first.

I think I can sort the vehicle objects in the ArrayList with comparator:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Vehicle vehicle1, Vehicle vehicle1) {
     return vehicle1.getTheNumberOfTimesUsed().compareTo(vehicle2.getTheNumberOfTimesUsed()());
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to change the places of items in **vehicleIDs** array depending on order in the ArrayList. Additionally, the vehicles, which have never been used must come fisrt.

Comment: Is it not possible to just create a new array from your sorted ArrayList?

Comment: No, it isn't.

As I said, only vehicles which used some amount of times are in the ArrayList.
And the vehicles, which have never been used must come first in the order of the items in vehicleIDs array after updating.

We are not allowed to add these unused vehicles to the ArrayList.

So, I have still need to update vehicleIDs array depending on the sorted Arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

In java there is no way you can directly change the order of elements in array.

However, you can create a new array (e.g. newVehicleIDs ) based on your sorted ArrayList, and you replace the value of your vehicleIDs array with the newly created array (vehicleIDs = newVehicleIDs;).

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList contains user defined objects. By using Collections.sort() method you can sort the ArrayList.

```
Collections.sort(list,new CompareVehicleIds())
```

You have to pass Comparator object which contains your sort logic.

```
class CompareVehicleIds implements Comparator<Object>{

         @Override
          public int compare(Vehicle vehicle1, Vehicle vehicle1) {
             return vehicle1.getTheNumberOfTimesUsed().compareTo(vehicle2.getTheNumberOfTimesUsed()());
            }
        }
```

Hope i was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Use the sorting algorithm you would use to sort normally, but take both arrays as parameters and use one for the comparisons. You would have to sort both to make it work. And of course, if there is no entry in the ArrayList for a specified ID, it must come first since it clearly has not been used.